# Google Docs API "setMd5Checksum" not working

Tags: java, md5, google-docs-api

Recently I've implemented an application in [Java](http://code.google.com/intl/es-ES/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_java.html) that uses the [Google Docs API v3.0](http://code.google.com/intl/es-ES/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html).  New entries are created like this:

```
DocumentListEntry newEntry = new  DocumentListEntry();
newEntry.setFile(file, Common.resolveMimeType(file)); //Common is a custom class
newEntry.setFilename(entryTitle.getPlainText()); //entryTitle is a TextConstruct
newEntry.setTitle(entryTitle); 
newEntry.setDraft(false);
newEntry.setHidden(file.isHidden());
newEntry.setMd5Checksum(Common.getMD5HexDigest(file));
```

Trust me when I tell you that `Common.getMD5HexDigest(file)` returns a valid and unique MD5 Hexadecimal hash.

Now, the file uploads properly yet when retrieving the file and checking the MD5 checksum through the `entry.getMd5Checksum()` method, it always returns `null`.

I've tried EVERYTHING, even set the `ETag`, `ResourceID` and `VersionID` but they all get override with default values (`null` or server generated strings).

Comment: Sorry, but I don't trust you if you claim that Common.getMD5HexDigest(file) returns a unique hash.

Comment: @jarnbjo I've updated the question with the method code.

Comment: So the hash you're working with is not just non-unique, but incorrect as well.

Comment: @jarnbjo It's unique since it's the MD5 hash of the file path hash (which is unique for every file in a Windows file system in any given PC). And how come it's not correct? I see 32 bytes of hexadecimal data.

Comment: Nit picking, the input may be unique, but the output might not be.

Comment: You might want to read up on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode() You're code isn't doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: @ChaimGeretz, @exabrial. The File `hashCode()` method overrides the Object `hasCode()` method and they do behave differently (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html). However, it doesn't matter if the MD5 hash is unique or not (which it is), it should only matter to my program's logic, the real problem is that the `setMd5Checksum()` method of the Google Docs API doesn't work when uploading a new entry, always returning `null` when getting the previously uploaded entry from Google Docs. Uniqueness of the MD5 hash is local, not world wide for every document in the world

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling a few weeks with the MD5 checksum problem (to verify if the content of the file changed over time), I came up with a solution that doesn't rely on the MD5 checksum of the file but on the client `last-update` attribute of the file.

This solution goes to everyone that wants to check if a file has changed over time. However, "an update" on any operating system can be considered as the act of opening the file and saving the file, with or without making any changes to the content of the file. So, it's not perfect but does save some time and bandwidth.

Solution:

```
long lastModified = new DateTime(
    new Date(file.lastModified()), TimeZone.getDefault()
).getValue();

if(lastModified > entry.getUpdated().getValue()) {
    //update the file
}
```

Where `file` is a `File` instance of the desired file and `entry` is the `DocumentListEntry` associated to the local file.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you need to set the checksum to the md5 hash of the file's ***contents***, not the hash of the *path-name*.

Why would they (google) care about the path? It makes no sense at all. Forgive me if I misinterpreted your code, but I think you have misconceived the concept of file checksums.

Anyway, what you need to do is eat (digest) the file and not the path:

```
   import java.security.*;
   import java.util.*;
   import java.math.*;
   import java.io.*;

   public class MD5 {
       private MessageDigest   mDigest;
       private File            openFile;
       private FileInputStream ofis;
       private int             fSize;  
       private byte[]          fBytes;

       public MD5(String filePath) {
           try { mDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5"); } 
           catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) { System.exit(1); }
           openFile = new File(filePath); 
       }   
       public String toString() {
           try {
               ofis    = new FileInputStream(openFile);
               fSize   = ofis.available();
               fBytes  = new byte[fSize];
               ofis.read(fBytes);
           } catch (Throwable t) {
               return "Can't read file or something";
           }  

           mDigest.update(fBytes);
           return new BigInteger(1, mDigest.digest()).toString(16);
       }  
       public static void main(String[] argv){
           MD5 md5 =  new MD5("someFile.ext");
           System.out.println(md5);
       }  
   }
```

So the error in your snippet above is here:

```
 messageDigest.update(String.valueOf(file.hashCode()).getBytes());
```

Now, I can show that my class gives the correct md5sum of the *file* which is most likely what you  need. Just read the javadoc of the method if you don't trust me: 
http://gdata-java-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/java/src/com/google/gdata/data/docs/DocumentListEntry.java
What it says is: 
* Set the MD5 checksum calculated for the document.
... nothing about the path's checksum :)

here:

```
$ echo "Two dogs are sleeping on my couch" > someFile.ext    
$ echo "Two dogs are sleeping on my couch" |md5sum 
1d81559b611e0079bf6c16a2c09bd994  -
$ md5sum someFile.ext 
1d81559b611e0079bf6c16a2c09bd994  someFile.ext
$ javac MD5.java && java MD5 
1d81559b611e0079bf6c16a2c09bd994
```

Comment: Actually, I see now that you are making an md5 sum from Java's hashCode-string and not the path. It's totally wrong. You need to md5-checksum-hash the flesh of file and not some random integer or whatever File.hashCode() creates.

Comment: Did that already, always returns `null`. I guess the `setMD5Checksum` method isn't supported at the moment.